# React Native: Display JSON data in Flatlist

Tags: react-native-flatlist

I am trying to get only "name" from below JSON response but it's not getting.Please help me...

```
JSON Response
```

```
data = "Data": {
    "0": {
        "Restaurant": {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Restaurant 1"
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "Restaurant": {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Restaurant 2"
        }
    }
}
```

> React Native Flatlist Code

```
<FlatList  
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({item}) =>                
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.restaurant_name}>{item.Restaurant.name}</Text> 
        </View>      
    }  
/>
```